# Group Policy for Microsoft Edge extensions

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

How can I configure my group policy, to forcefully install a specific extension to MS Edge on client machines?

Now that Edge is starting to support more extensions, and better ones, this is becoming a valid option for secure browsing. If I want to allow my users to use Edge, I would expect them all to have required security extensions - e.g. ad blocker (specifically I like [uBlock origin](https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/app/9nblggh444l4), but there are others), and any other required extension...

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, Edge extensions are installed through the Windows Store.
Therefor any extensions you need to install you would need to follow the same steps as distributing any other Windows Store app.

If you use System Center Configuration Manager you can do this fairly easily: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/manage-apps-from-the-windows-store-for-business

Heres some more information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-offline-apps

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Edge Download Page here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download) and select Get Policy Files to get the Edge admx and adl files for your PolicyDefinitions in your DC.

Then go to your policy manager and Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates: Policy Definitions > Microsoft Edge > Extensions.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZI2A.png) is a screenshot of what worked for me. I used the value `cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx` to install ublock origin. Unfortunately I don't recall where I got this value.